# BaseFieldDefinition change DB column type

Tags: 8, entities, database

In a content entity definition, I've got the following:

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

  $fields['frames'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
    ->setLabel(t('Frames'))
  ->setDescription('A serialized representation of the given frames');

  return $fields;
}
```

This is creating the column type in the database as varchar, with a maxlength of 255. I need the column to be type text, as the length will be unknown, and often more than 255. Does anybody know how to create a BaseFieldDefinition that becomes type 'text' in the database when the content entity is enabled?

Comment: Try `BaseFieldDefinition::create('text')` or `BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')`

Comment: I tried that, and it only adds a _format column to the table, but leaves the original column as varchar

Answer (score 1):

`BaseFieldDefinition::create('string_long')` creates a LONGTEXT database column without the extra *_format* column.